# How can I move slider text from behind div

Tags: css

Here is link to slider all CSS can be seen inline in source code! Any help would be great just want to move text into gray background and keep image in place!

http://www.postrealty.net/test_site/index_test.html

Comment: Please don't post external link. Post your code with explanations of what you tried to do

Comment: Hi @Craig Gallup can you explain better what do you want to do?